# How to select non-adjacent ranges or cells of excel using xlwings in Python?

Tags: python, xlwings

I wonder if there's a way to select non-adjacent ranges or cells simultaneously of excel using xlwings in Python, cause i dont want to use loop for that.

```
xlwings.Range(xlwings.Range('a1:b4'), xlwings.Range('b8:d10')).color=(255,0,0)
```

I want to color Range('a1:b4') and Range('b8:d10') so i used the above code but it colored the Range('a1:d10'). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just the following will do what you want.

```
import xlwings as xw


path = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App() as app:
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    ws = xw.sheets.active

    # ws.Range(xlwings.Range('a1:b4'), xlwings.Range('b8:d10')).color=(255,0,0)

    ws.range("A1:B4,B8:D10").color=(255,0,0)
    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```